# Why can't work coffee function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I can't figure out why can't my code call handleOutboundLinkClicks.
restaurant.coffee is this. It's under app/assets/javascript.

```
handleOutboundLinkClicks = (event)->
  alert 'hahaha'
  ga 'send', 'event',
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link'
    eventAction: 'click'
    eventLabel: event.target.href
    transport: 'beacon'
  return
```

Also application.js is like this.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
(abbr.)
//= require restaurant
```

My view is here.

```
  dl
    dt =  t :restaurant_list_url
    dd = link_to @restaurant.url, @restaurant.url, :target => "_blank", :onclick => "handleOutboundLinkClicks(this);"
```

The error is like this.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: handleOutboundLinkClicks is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

Comment: is `handleOutboundLinkClicks()` a global function? like, does `window.handleOutboundLinkClicks` reference this function?

Comment: I changed handleOutboundLinkClicks() into window.handleOutboundLinkClicks() though, But still same. Any idea?

Comment: You'd need to do it the other way around: `window.handleOutboundLinkClicks = (event) -> ...`. Or better, add a class attribute to the links and bind a click handler without the old school `onclick` attribute and global function.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.